# How can I find the website using a specific host header name?

Tags: iis-6

Ive been asked to help locate and understand a website running on an older WIN2K3 server.  That means IIS6.  There are a lot of websites on it and most of them are using host headers.  So I have the domain name of the website and ive traced it to the server where its hosted.  Im remoted in to the server but Id rather not have to look through all of them to find the specific site.  None of them are named in such a way that its obvious.

So, can I find a website on a server, given the host header its using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the all bindings here:

`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml`

This file should hold most IIS config settings. Make sure you back it up before modifying it!

Comment: Thats it!  Thank you.  Didnt need to modify anything, just take a look to find a needle in a haystack.